# OpenQA cant detect my chromedriver webdriver

Tags: selenium

can someone tell me why i keep getting an error while running this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("@C:/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx xxx/xxx/chromedriver");
```

the error said that the file "chromedriver.exe" doesnt exist but it is in that folder. I downloaded the chromedriver file again through the link that the error gave me. still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add more info like what error you got with error stack trace, what you tried, and all?

Comment: "Exception Unhandled. OpenQA,Selenium.DriverService.NotFoundException: ´The file @C:/User/xxx/xxx/xxx xxx/xxx/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://chrome..." Because of the double "chromedriver" in the path I tried to direct it just to the folder. didn't work. i downloaded it again from the link in the error. didn't work. now I don't know what else to do